# Query an ActiveRecord on several tables?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Sorry to ask this question but I'm really newbie with Ruby and I need help to update several records on my database.

I'm using ActiveRecord to query the database. Let say I have a table Product that contains SubProduct that also contains SubSubProduct. Now I would like to write a simple query to get all SubSubProduct of Product.

To get a list of SubSubProduct I usually do this

```
ssp = SubSubProduct.where(sub_sub_type: "example")
```

Now to use a where clause on relational element how can I do

```
ssp = SubSubProduct.where(sub_sub_type: "example", SubProduct.Product.type: "sample")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up ActiveRecord associations in your models:

```
#app/models/product.rb:
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_products
end

#app/models/sub_product.rb:
class SubProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end

#app/models/sub_sub_product.rb:
class SubSubProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sub_product
end
```

What you wanted:

```
ssp = SubSubProduct.where(sub_sub_type: "example", SubProduct.Product.my_type: "sample")
```

The correct syntax:

```
ssp = SubSubProduct.includes(sub_product: :product).where(sub_sub_type:"example", products: {my_type: "toto"})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is performed via associations.

```
class SubSubProduct
  has_many  :products
end
```

Then you can do things like

```
sub_product.products
```

and it will product all the products associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

Try a nested includes:

`Product.includes(subproducts: :subsubproducts)'

Answer (score 0):

For this, you'll want to set up ActiveRecord associations in your models:

In product.rb:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_products
  has_many :sub_sub_products, through: :sub_products
end
```

In sub_product.rb:

```
class SubProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :sub_sub_products
end
```

In sub_sub_product.rb:

```
class SubSubProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sub_product
end
```

Then, if you have a Product and want its SubSubProducts, you can use:

```
# p is a Product object
p.sub_sub_products
```